# Angular data binding object in value attribute of option in select

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `select` item which I'm populating using `ng-repeat` in `option`. I use angular's data binding to set the value of the selected item to my model. But 
for some reason the " in the json string are now turned into \" . Because of this I can't reach the attributes in the json string anymore later on in my code.

```
<select id="concepts" class="form-control"     ng-model='usecase.concepts'  multiple title='-Select one or more primary concepts-' data-width="auto" >
        <option  ng-repeat='concept in concepten' value='{{concept}}'>{{concept.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Concept JSON string looks like this:

```
{"name":"Concept1","description":"beschrijving"}
```

but when I select an item in the select it looks like this:

```
{\"name\":\"Concept1\",\"description\":\"beschrijving\"}
```

I later on want to fill some dropdowns with the name attribute of the chosen concepts, but I can't reach the name attribute anymore because of the backslash. 
How can I fix this so  `value` doesn't add backslashed to the JSON string?

**remark:** It works perfectly using `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`, but I'm trying to use the [nya-bootstrap-select](http://nya.io/nya-bootstrap-select/#!/) which I can't get to work with the `ng-options` tag

Comment: try using angular.fromJson(); to parse the json to a javascript object - then you should be able to access it properly

Comment: @deolectrix is it possible to do this parsing in the select object? or should I  parse the model afterwards?

Comment: you should try and parse the json before hand, so when you are assigning it to `$scope.usecase.concepts`, so you might have something like this. `$scope.usecase.concepts = []`, `$scope.usecase.concepts.push(angular.fromJson({"name":"Concept1","description":"beschrijving"}));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend to put whole JSON-Strings as Value in the select. If your description contains more text / html you might run into trouble. 
It might be better to set the selected concepts in a change handler like:

```
ng-change="updateSelectedConcepts()"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4ETrFlM0HrftAobTyvtS?p=preview

In the plunkr you can see, that the `usecase.concepts` contains the selected concepten-objects.